# Discord embed images not loading (Replit, Python)

Tags: python, discord

I've uploaded a sample image on Replit, and I am trying to embed it in a Discord message using a bot. I can create the embed just fine, but the image never seems to load, like such:

[image: discord embed]

If I click on the failed image and open original, it brings me to the page with the image correctly. I believe the problem may be that I'm not properly linking the image, or that Discord is not recognizing that the link is an image. Code:

```
if message.content.startswith('$img'):
   e = discord.Embed(title="Title", description="Desc", color=0x00ff00)
   e.set_image(url='https://replit.com/@Shazamin/Mythic-Tamer#images/species/slime.png')
   await message.channel.send(embed=e)
```

Comment: https://replit.com/@Shazamin/Mythic-Tamer#images/species/slime.png is not a valid image file.

Comment: https://replit.com/@Shazamin/Mythic-Tamer#images/species/slime.png is the link I get when I 'copy link' from the image I uploaded to Replit - if it is not a valid image file (rather just a page with the image I assume?) then is there a way I can reference it as a valid image file?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution, if anyone needs this in the future:

```
if message.content.startswith('$img'):
   e = discord.Embed(title="Title", description="Desc", color=0x00ff00)
   file = discord.File("images/species/slime.png", filename="image.png")
   e.set_image(url="attachment://image.png")
   await message.channel.send(file=file, embed=e)
```

Found the answer here: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-do-i-use-a-local-image-file-for-an-embed-image